# Python argparse: default value or specified value

Tags: python, default-value, argparse

I would like to have a optional argument that will default to a value if only the flag is present with no value specified, but store a user-specified value instead of the default if the user specifies a value. Is there already an action available for this?

An example:

```
python script.py --example
# args.example would equal a default value of 1
python script.py --example 2
# args.example would equal a default value of 2
```

I can create an action, but wanted to see if there was an existing way to do this.

Answer (score 444, accepted):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--example', nargs='?', const=1, type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

---

```
% test.py 
Namespace(example=None)
% test.py --example
Namespace(example=1)
% test.py --example 2
Namespace(example=2)
```

---

- `nargs='?'` means 0-or-1 arguments
- `const=1` sets the default when there are 0 arguments
- `type=int` converts the argument to int

---

If you want `test.py` to set `example` to 1 even if no `--example` is specified, then include `default=1`. That is, with

```
parser.add_argument('--example', nargs='?', const=1, type=int, default=1)
```

then

```
% test.py 
Namespace(example=1)
```

Comment: How to do this with strings? I have a dilemma with differentiation of "" (empty string as default) and "" (empty string as entered by user). In the code for now I'm using the default and since I need to do some ops, I have something like this `self.foo = (args.bar or some_else_source).upper()`. It will break on None object AFAIUC.

Comment: BE CAREFUL; if you try to have positional args **afterwards**, the first position arg will become the value for `--example` (if it doesn't have an explicit one).  Just spent 10 minutes debugging that!

Comment: is there a way to make it accept an optional int and still distinguish a positional string argument?

Answer (score 100):

The difference between:

```
parser.add_argument("--debug", help="Debug", nargs='?', type=int, const=1, default=7)
```

and

```
parser.add_argument("--debug", help="Debug", nargs='?', type=int, const=1)
```

is thus:

`myscript.py`           => debug is 7 (from default) in the first case and "None" in the second

`myscript.py --debug`   => debug is 1 in each case

`myscript.py --debug 2` => debug is 2 in each case

Comment: Excellent way to describe this difference

Comment: There is a contradiction between your answer and the previous answer... According to previous answer: myscript.py --debug should bring 7

Comment: You’re welcome to test the code for yourself. If I’ve made a mistake it’s helpful for us all. 
However, I believe I have correctly described the results of my testing. 
Test.py gives 7 because no —debug argument was provided so the default value is used. 
Test.py —debug gives 1, the value set by const.

Comment: There may be issues with running code, but this answer does correctly demonstrate how to assign default values with argparse, which is the crux of the question.