# Python argparse override help from parent

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

I have a CLI I'm building which utilizes subparsers for sub-commands similar to tools like git. Some of my sub-commands share common options so I have a group parser that defines the options, and each sub-command that needs them uses `parents=group_parser` as one of the arguments. For example:

```
group_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group_parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', action='store_true')

command1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command1', parents=[group_parser])
command2_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command2', parents=[group_parser])
```

So as you see both command1 and command2 inherit the option `--foo`. What I'm trying to do is update the helptext for foo separately on command1 and command2. For instance if I run `myprog command1 -h`, I want it to say a different help message for `--foo` that when I run `myprog command2 -h`. The problem is until I do `parse_args()` there isn't a namespace to update for that argument, so something like this doesn't work:

```
group_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group_parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', action='store_true')

command1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command1', parents=[group_parser])
command1.foo['help'] = "foo help for command1"
command2_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command2', parents=[group_parser])
command2.foo['help'] = "foo help for command2"
```

Is this possible to somehow add additional parameters to an argument outside of the `add_argument()` function? The only other solution is to not use the inherited parent and just define foo separately for each sub-command, but if there's a way to update parameters, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way of changing the `help` (and other Action attributes) after the Action (argument) has been created.  But with the `parents` mechanism there's another problem - Actions are copied by reference.  So even if you can change the `help` for `command1`, you end up changing it for `command2` as well.  I've encountered this when trying to change attributes like `default`.

I'll add an illustration, and may be a link to previous discussions.

```
In [2]: parent = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
In [4]: fooObj = parent.add_argument('--foo',default='foo1', help='foo help')
```

`fooObj` is a reference to the Action created by this `add_argument`.

```
In [5]: fooObj.default
Out[5]: 'foo1'
In [6]: fooObj.help      # the help parameter        
Out[6]: 'foo help'
In [7]: parent.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  --foo FOO  foo help
```

changing the help attribute:

```
In [8]: fooObj.help = 'new help'
In [9]: parent.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  --foo FOO  new help
```

Now make a parser and subparsers

```
In [10]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [11]: sp = parser.add_subparsers()
In [13]: cmd1 = sp.add_parser('cmd1',parents=[parent])
In [14]: cmd2 = sp.add_parser('cmd2',parents=[parent])

In [15]: cmd2.print_help()
usage: ipython3 cmd2 [-h] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   new help
```

`_actions` is a list of the arguments defined for a parser:

```
In [16]: cmd1._actions
Out[16]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default='foo1', type=None, choices=None, help='new help', metavar=None)]
```

Comparing ids we can see that the 2d action is the same as `fooObj`.  Same with `cmd2`.

```
In [17]: id(cmd1._actions[1])
Out[17]: 2885458060
In [18]: id(fooObj)
Out[18]: 2885458060
```

Changing the `help` for `cmd1` changes it for `cmd2` as well

```
In [19]: cmd1._actions[1].help = 'cmd1 foo'
In [20]: cmd2.print_help()
usage: ipython3 cmd2 [-h] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   cmd1 foo
In [21]: fooObj.help
Out[21]: 'cmd1 foo'
```

Here's a case of trying to provide different defaults for the subparsers:

[argparse - Combining parent parser, subparsers and default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666197/argparse-combining-parent-parser-subparsers-and-default-values)

It might be best to use your own utility function(s) to add the common arguments to the subparsers.  That way each subparser can have its own copy of the Action objects, rather than sharing them.  I think the `parents` mechanism is nicer in theory than in practice.

Comment: This is very informative, and thanks for the links to the other discussions. This clearly answers the question and gave me a lot of useful information for various solutions. Parents does still seem useful in cases where the commands are literally identical, for instance --debug and some other options that are exactly the same in every way for each sub-command. For the args that share the same name but are used slightly differently (hence needing different help commands) I simply split them up and made a separate `add_parser` lines for each.