# Argparse: How to create the equivalent of const with nargs='*'

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to produce the equivalent of `const` (that we can use with `nargs='?'`, see [reference question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301147/python-argparse-default-value-or-specified-value) for an example), but for `nargs='*'`. Meaning that I would want:

```
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('--option', nargs='*', const=[1, 2, 3])
print(argparser.parse_args())
```

And then during usage:

```
my_script.py               #  Namespace(option=None)
my_script.py --option      #  Namespace(option=[1, 2, 3])
my_script.py --option 4 5  #  Namespace(option=[4, 5])
```

Currently I get `ValueError: nargs must be '?' to supply const`

Comment: Without the `const` the second case should produce `option=[]`.  You could easily detect and replace that after parsing.

Comment: The error message you get comes from an explicit test in the `store` Action class "if const is not None and nargs != OPTIONAL:".  In `_get_values` 'OPTIONAL' has a special step to handle `const`.  Other `nargs` do not.  `_get_values` is called before the `Action's` `__call__`.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, but checking "empty but not None" feels a bit odd. `const` is more straightforward. Why is argparse not enabling const with `*`? It's just inconsistent...

Comment: @mara004, I used to follow the bug/issues religiously, and don't recall any suggesting expending the use of `const.  I don't know the thinking of the original developer, but my guess is the `const` was included for use by 'store_const' and its sublclass 'store_true'..  Its use in the 3 way '?' is a bonus.  If `argparse` doesn't do everything you want it's perfect ok (even encouraged) to write a custom action class, or to do your own post-parsing checking.

Comment: Part of the style issue with checking against `[]` is that a) we can't use `default=[]` anymore; b) We rely on the detail of `nargs="*"` producing a list, not a tuple.
So you'd have to do `if args.myarg is None: {default}; elif not args.myarg: {const}`. Not very idiomatic IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [`action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) to achieve this outcome:

```py
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()

class customAction(argparse.Action):
    """
    Customized argparse action, will set the
    value in the following way:

        1) If no option_string is supplied: set to None

        2) If option_string is supplied:

            2A) If values are supplied:
                set to list of values

            2B) If no values are supplied:
                set to default value (`self.const`)

    NOTES:
        If `const` is not set, default value (2A) will be None
    """
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if option_string:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.const)
        elif not values:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, None)
        else:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)


p.add_argument('--option',
    nargs='*',
    action=customAction,
    dest='option',
    type=int,
    const=[1, 2, 3]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a little 'overkill' for the context of my work but it does work!

Answer (score 0):

Simplification of @YaakovBressler's code:

```py
class ConstWithMultiArgs (argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        obj = values if values else self.const if option_string else self.default
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, obj)
```